# LibGDX matrix changes rotation after creating

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a program on libgdx, it is a game engine, for five years of working on the program there seemed to be no problems with matrices, but today I discovered a strange problem, I create a matrix with the desired position, rotation and scaling, then I check the rotation of this matrix, and miracle! rotation has changed!
Here is the code, just for testing:

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Quaternion rot = new Quaternion(0.70710677, 0, 0, 0.70710677);
Vector3 scl = new Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

Matrix4 mat = new Matrix4(pos, rot, scl);

Gdx.app.log("mat", mat.getTranslation(new Vector3()).toString() +" / "+ mat.getRotation(new Quaternion()).toString() +" / "+ mat.getScale(new Vector3()).toString());

//return:
//[mat] (0.0,0.0,0.0) / [-0.40824825|0.0|0.0|0.61237246] / (0.5,0.49999997,0.49999997)
```

As you can see, the rotation has changed, and the scaling has changed a little, although no actions were performed on the matrix,

I'm trying to make a 3d model compiler, due to this error I can't make the correct bind pose

Tried creating the matrix in different ways

```
Matrix4 mat = new Matrix4().setToTranslationAndScaling(pos, scl);
mat.rotate(rot);
```

But the result is the same